# Move a pin according to the position of the user

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my iPhone application, I want to drop a pin at my current location using mapView and I also need to move another pin or a ball as my position changes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display user location, just add :

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

To get it, use the method `userLocation` which gives you a `MKUserLocation`.

You can then add a `id<MKAnnotation>` object with `addAnnotation` method to display another pin.